# Object sort order is wrong

Tags: php, modx-revolution, xpdo

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with the sort order on an xPDO SQL query,

This query

```
$criteria = $this->modx->newQuery($table);
$criteria->sortby($sortby,$sortdir);
$options = $this->modx->getCollectionGraph($table,$criteria);
$criteria->prepare();
echo '<pre>'.$criteria->toSQL().'</pre>';
```

results in this SQL ~ which is correct:

```
SELECT `Location`.`id` AS `Location_id`, `Location`.`created` AS `Location_created`,
 `Location`.`modified` AS `Location_modified`, `Location`.`location` AS 
`Location_location`, `Location`.`group` AS `Location_group`, `Location`.`comment` 
AS `Location_comment` 
FROM `flow_location` AS `Location` ORDER BY location asc
```

however, if I try to loop over the query:

```
foreach($options as $option) {
    echo $option->get($value).'<br>';
}
```

it will display the records by the order id in the database!?

how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by `location asc`, but `location` is not defined in your query. You rename column `location` to `Location_location`, so you should order by `Location_location asc`.

```
SELECT `Location`.`id` AS `Location_id`, `Location`.`created` AS `Location_created`,
 `Location`.`modified` AS `Location_modified`, `Location`.`location` AS 
`Location_location`, `Location`.`group` AS `Location_group`, `Location`.`comment` 
AS `Location_comment` 
FROM `flow_location` AS `Location` ORDER BY location asc
```

Comment: If I run that query in an sql browser it does work & order correctly - I see what you are saying trying to order by Location_location yeilds the same result [$criteria->sortby($table.'_'.$sortby,$sortdir); I'm not sure you can sort getCollectionGraph, because the code does work if I just use 'getCollection'

Comment: Gotcha. Dont know much about modx, but you could sort the object after the query in php with a usort() function. Seach SO for some examples